# Pandas resample does not give expected result

Tags: pandas, aggregate

I have a dataframe (dislayed below) which I want to aggregate on the daily. To accomplish this, I set the datetime column as index and use `df = df.resample('D').agg(max)` such that I can aggregate on the daily. However, it does not seem to work at all. What is wrong with my approach?

original dataframe:

[image: original dataframe]

resulting dataframe:

[image: resulting dataframe]

Comment: Hi, could you please include a small subset of your data as a copyable piece of code that can be used for testing as well as your expected output for the provided data?

Comment: can you paste sample CSVs (with around 10 rows each) in raw comma-separated format, not parsed-dataframe format. and also show your expected output